# Retrieve Asana metadata with Python

Tags: python, api, asana, asana-api

I've managed to install PyCharm CE and the Python Asana library (https://github.com/Asana/python-asana).

I can connect, retrieve projects, tasks and subtasks. But for tasks and subtasks, it always seem to only return the `id` and `name`.

How can I retrieve other metadata?

```
import asana
import json
from six import print_


# create a client with your Asana API key
client = asana.Client.basic_auth('<MyAPIkey')

me = client.users.me()
#print_("me=" + json.dumps(me, indent=2))

# find your "Personal Projects" project
# personal_projects = next(workspace for workspace in me['workspaces'] if  workspace['name'] == 'Personal Projects')
# projects = client.projects.find_by_workspace(personal_projects['id'], iterator_type=None)
# print_("personal projects=" + json.dumps(projects, indent=2))

# find "Lithium" project
lithium_projects = next(workspace for workspace in me['workspaces'] if workspace['name'] == 'lithium.com')
projects = client.projects.find_by_workspace(lithium_projects['id'], iterator_type=None)
#print_("Lithium projects=" + json.dumps(projects, indent=2))

for project in projects:
    #print_ ("id", project['id'] )
    print_ ("")
    print_ ("Project", project['name'] )
    project_id = project['id']
    project_tasks = client.tasks.find_by_project(project_id, iterator_type=None)

    for task in project_tasks:
        #print_("Tasks=" + json.dumps(task, indent=2))
        print_ ("  Task ", task['id'], ":", task['name'] )
        task_id = task['id']
        task_subtasks = client.tasks.subtasks(task_id, full_payload=True)

        for subtask in task_subtasks:
            print_("    Sub-tasks=" + json.dumps(subtask, indent=2))
            #print_ (subtask['id'], ":", subtask['name'] )
```

Short example of results:

```
Project X
  Task  32131361438409 : [Case] Title1
  Task  32131361438400 : [Case] Title2
    Sub-tasks={
    "id": 32131361438402, 
    "name": "1:1 Subtask1"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Requests that return a collection of objects use the compact format to represent the objects.

You can use [field selectors](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/input-output-options) to specify exactly what metadata you would like included for each task or subtask.

For instance, if you wanted to always have the `notes` field included in responses your request might look like:

```
project_tasks = client.tasks.find_by_project(project_id, {"opt_fields":"this.notes"},  iterator_type=None)
```